# Using Insert with 2 selects inside in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Here's what i'm trying to do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO LocationGeofencePoint( PointNo, Latitude, Longitude)
        VALUES ( (SELECT LocationGeofenceID FROM LocationGeofence WHERE GeofenceName='".$name."'), 
                (SELECT MAX(PointNo)+1 FROM LocationGeofencePoint),
                 '".$lat."',
                 '".$long."')";
```

But this happens.

[image]
Every time I add "" the 2nd select stops working.

These are 2 separate tables LocationGeofencePoint and LocationGeofence and I'm trying to get values from LocationGeofence into LocationGeofencePoint.

The result should be something like
LocationGeofencePoint(2 , 14, 54.333, 55.435) (these would be the values)

LocationGeofence(2, Test , group1) (trying to get this '2' into location geofencepoint)

I also tried it just in case it was my editor bugging out but it isn't and i've run out of ideas , any idea on what I can do ? I tried separating the queries but I also need 2 selects to run the 2nd one and that isn't working.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others understand what you want to do.  Similarly, are you using MySQL or Azure?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: one thing you can try is wrp your columns and table names within `backticks(``)`, so it will be easier for us to understand

Comment: @GordonLinoff is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO LocationGeofencePoint( PointNo, Latitude, Longitude)
        VALUES ( (SELECT LocationGeofenceID FROM LocationGeofence WHERE GeofenceName='".$name."'), 
                (SELECT MAX(PointNo)+1 FROM LocationGeofencePoint),
                 '".$lat."',
                 '".$long."')";
```

Put same number of column in insert fields and as well as its column values.

Answer (score 1):

First, `GeoReferencePoint` should be declared as an `identity` column.  You should not be incrementing the value on insert.  The database does that for you.

Then, you should be using `insert . . . select`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO LocationGeofencePoint (PointNo, Latitude, Longitude)
            SELECT LocationGeofenceID, $lat, $long
            FROM LocationGeofence
            WHERE GeofenceName = '".$name."';
```

And third, this is not right either.  The three values being passed in should be using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'stop working' as the color is not the same color with the first SELECT?

If so, don't worry it just the editor's problem. You will achieve the desired result once you run the code. I experience the same before.